# Encrypting a textfield in HTML

Tags: html, encryption, textfield, password-encryption

I have a text field in my HTML project that I want to encrypt as a password.

So basicaslly instead of this being displayed in the text field:

```
mypassword
```

I want it to say:

```
*********
```

or something close to that.
So basically just making the text that the user inputs not to be visible.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<input type="password" />`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `<input type="password" />`.

Note that this has **nothing** to do with encryption.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with encryption, it's just a [form field type](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/i/inputpassword.htm), you can use the following:

```
<input type="password" name="password"/>
```

However, uploading whatever is entered in here when the user submits will send it plainly across the internet unless you're using [HTTPS with a valid SSL certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure), which will encrypt all communications between the user and your site and is recommended for anything with a login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `< input type="password" >` like this to hide your password with stars.but it is not enough when you upload your password .you should use PHP or something else

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your existing code where you put your textbox

```
<input type="password" name="password"/>
```

This will not let you see what you enter and code it with stars, as default.